# MySQL Notifier: Error subscribing to WMI Events: RPC_E_CALL_CANCELLED. Exception HRESULT: 0x80010002

Tags: mysql, exception, mysql-workbench, hresult, mysql-notifier

At every startup in Windows I get an error message by MySQL Notifier:

[image]

Does anybody know how to get rid of this?

If this is because of Firewall, my question is if anybody has a solution, instead of turning Firewall off.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same error on my Windows 7 Professional computer but it does not appear every time I log in.
I saw a hyperlink on a MySQL forum that may help:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/windows-notifier-installation.html
Check that your MySQL service or daemon is running. In my case I have two versions of MySQL installed on my computer but only one of them is set to start up automatically. This might be why I get the message.